# no such file to load -- rubygems

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I learn Ralis by [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).
It is very interesting. 
I have one trouble. 
I create new app.  I done many work. But I reinstall my system (Ubuntu 13.04 -> 12.xx). 
My folder with new app saved. 
I want to continue work with it.
I installed rvm,ruby,rails. 
I installed all gems for this app successful.
I run migrations.
I can view my app in Chrome :)
But when I want to do tests:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

it generate error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:8
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:11
from /usr/bin/bundle:4:in `require'
from /usr/bin/bundle:4
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you need to pass in a directory name or file name where your tests are located to the rspec command?

Comment: please provide an output of `which ruby`, `which rvm`, `which gem`, `ruby -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall all components (ruby rails rvm etc)  and move project folder to ~/  and it works. :)